# Using a self variable as a python method parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I use my self variable as the method parameter such that I can achieve this:

```
myclass = My_Class(arg1=3)
output = myclass(1,2) # If the third argument is not given, use the self.arg1 variable
output = myclass(1,2,10) # If the third argument is given, use it instead of self.arg1
```

I tried the following code but it gives me an error

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        
    def foo(self, x,y,z=self.arg1):
        return (x+y)**z
```

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You can't refer to `self.arg1` in the parameter list like that.

Comment: The default value is evaluated only once at class initialization time. At this point no instance of the class and therefore no `self` exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that this might normally be done is to use `None` as the default parameter.

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        
    def foo(self, x, y, z=None):
        if z is None:
            z = self.arg1
        return (x+y)**z
```

Answer (score 2):

@2ps answer is excellent and is generally the accepted way to go. I just want to add that, if `None` is actually a valid argument to your function and you want to distinguish between `None` and "I didn't provide an argument", a little trick I've used in the past is to make my own private "none"-like object that no one else has access to.

```
_no_arg = object()

class My_Class():
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        
    def foo(self, x, y, z=_no_arg):
        if z is _no_arg:
            z = self.arg1
        return (x+y)**z
```